# How to modify a value in textual data file using C

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, file, file-io

```
while(!feof(fp)) 
{
    fscanf(fp,"%d %s %d %d",&res[i].id,res[i].title,&res[i].price,&res[i].qty);
    i++;
}
while(j<i)
{
    printf("\nID:|%d|\tNAME:|%s|\tPRICE:|%d|\tQTY:|%d|",res[j].id,res[j].title,res[j].price,res[j].qty);
    j++;
}
```

I have this piece of code which is collecting data from the file. Now I want to know if get an input from a user like `res[id]` and I want to decrease the quantity of that particular id how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in binary format it is easier to do what you want.

What is the difference between the text and the binary format? If the file is written in binary format, then a 32-bit integer will be represented as 32 consecutive bits in the file. While in text format the number will be represented as sequence of digits for instance `32`.

So what's the big deal in that difference? Well if you replace 32 with 1243, in binary format the number will still take the same 32 bits so nothing else needs to be moved, all you change is these 4 bytes. While in the second case you add 2 more digits which will cause all the subsequent contents of the file to shift with two bytes.

In order to shift everything as needed, you will need to read the current contents of the file  change the value and then write the contents back. I mean all the contents following the change you are doing.